# Return to same page in pagination

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

```
| Item | Stock | Description | Action 
| Book | 5     | PHP Books   | Edit   
| Pen  | 14    | Gold Pen    | Edit   
| Pen2 | 2     | Silver Pen  | Edit   

|Previous|1|2|**3**|4|5|Next|
```

i have some items in my table on page 3, i wanna edit an item and when i click save the data, i wanna return to this table with same page.

now, when i click save, i will return to page 1

maybe you have the reference to read, or something because i don't know the keyword.

Comment: Include the reference to the page they were on on the save button's link.

Comment: How do you get your page number ? Can you not pass it by `GET` like `index.php?page=2` then all you have to do is `$page = $_GET['page']`

Comment: Could you use HTTP_REFERER ? $url_to_redirect_after_save = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?? base_url('default/to/page/1');

Comment: Edit your question what code you have tried with.

Answer (score 0):

Add the page number in a hidden field in the form.

After form submission, redirect to that page

The page number is the argument you are passing to your controller function: **public function index(**`$page_nbr` **= 0)**

Here is an example:

```
public function index($page_nbr = 0)
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = '/users/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->users_model->count_users();
    $config['per_page'] = 40;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['current_page_number'] = $page_nbr;
    $this->run('users', $data);     
}
```

Comment: hmm, how to get the page number?

Comment: You already have it in your controller. It should be the argument you are passing to your function